# Using SmartPointers with operator '++'

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

How can I change the code below to have unique_ptr instead of the traditional pointer?

```
// vector::data
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector (5);

  int* p = myvector.data();

  *p = 10;
  ++p;
  *p = 20;
  p[2] = 100;

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (unsigned i=0; i<myvector.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

I tried the code below, but I am having E0349 no operator "++" matches these operands

```
  unique_ptr<int> p {myvector.data()};

  *p = 10;
  ++p; // <<< ERROR HERE >>>
```

Comment: Why do think you can change the address managed by a smart pointer and allow it to still be properly managed?

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. Look at the smart pointers as data (or resource) *ownership* instead of just plain self-deleting pointers. The data is owned and managed by the vector, you should not attempt to manage it yourself.

Comment: Why are you using a smart pointer for this purpose to begin with? Seems like cargo cult programming.

Comment: You don't ... You're telling the unique ptr to take ownership of the vector's data ... When it goes out of scope, it will delete the vector's data, then the vector will need try to delete its own data, and now you have a double free scenario.

Comment: You shouldn't do that: the `unique_ptr` would take ownership of memory which is already managed by `vector`. This would result in a double `delete`.

Comment: Putting the result of `myvector.data()` into a `unique_ptr` is dangerous, as both `myvector` and the `unique_ptr` each assume they have sole responsibility for managing that data.   The result is undefined behaviour in various ways (e.g. when `myvector` ceases to exist it releases the memory (collection of objects) it manages then, later, the `unique_ptr`  releases the SAME memory).    Also, incrementing the (raw pointer in) a `unique_ptr` means that the pointer no longer points at an object that can be released - but `unique_ptr` *will* eventually release it (that's its job).

Comment: Thank you for all the comments... It is really appreciated.

Comment: In modern C++, the generally considered best practice is to use a smart container (like `std::vector`, or `std::array`, or `std::unique_ptr`, or `std::string`) to own the contained objects and manage their lifespan, and use **raw pointers** as *non-owning* pointers.  Ideally.  In practice, there's tons of legacy code and new code following legacy practices that have owning raw pointers to deal with.

Answer (score 5):

Smart pointers are not meant to manage individual elements of bulk data. The intent purpose of smart pointers is to manage the allocation and lifetime of complex objects.

Container objects like `std::vector` have *iterators* for the express purpose to wrap access to their bulk data internal elements without exposing a naked pointer. Use those!

Answer (score 3):

In your code `std::vector` is responsible for memory management, so feeding here any smart pointer is pointless.

Forcing `std::unique_ptr` to interact with `std::vector` will only break things, since both are implemented with assumption they are only objects responsible to manage memory owned by them.

The only whay to introduce smart pointer here, is this, but `std::vector` solution is better:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main ()
{
  auto unique = std::make_unique<int[]>(5);

  int* p = unique.get();

  *p = 10;
  ++p;
  *p = 20;
  p[2] = 100;

  std::cout << "unique_ptr contains:";
  for (unsigned i=0; i<5; ++i)
    std::cout << ' ' << unique[i];
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Please remember that smart pointer help to mange memory. Basically smart pointer moves responsibility of releasing memory from developer to compiler and compiler is more reliable then human.

Now since smart pointer is responsible for managing memory it should always point to same location. `++` and `--` do not have seance for them. To iterate over c-like arrays you should use raw pointers.

Answer (score 3):

`myvector.data();` returns a pointer to the internal representation of the vector.
You should not initialise a `std::unique_ptr<>` with it because the `unique_ptr<>` will `delete` the array when it is destructed but so will the vector (when destructed or reallocated [e.g. resized]). The result is undefined.

Secondly and separately there is no valid meaning to incrementing a `unique_ptr<>` because you should only `delete` a pointer that was allocated. Passing a pointer to 'within' an allocated object to `delete` rather than a pointer to it's start also has undefined consequences.

In both cases the behaviour is undefined and in practice usually catastrophic (results in corruption of the heap leading to who-knows-what).

Answer (score 2):

> I am having E0349 no operator "++" matches these operands

The **problem**(mentioned error) is that [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) has not overloaded `operator++` and hence this `operator++` cannot be used with it which is what the compiler is trying to say in *"no operator "++" matches these operands"*.

##### Note

Also, note that memory in containers might get reallocated and then if you use(like by dereferencing etc) the old pointers that still point to the old memory, you will get **undefined behavior**.